# Split a string to K substrings using List Comprehension

Tags: python

I have a long string with me like this

`s = 'abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdefghi'`

I want to split it to K substrings, where each substring must be at least of length  1 ie non-empty. I want all such possible combinations.

The output I am expecting must be like following if `K` is 3

```
[['abcda', 'bcdabcdabcda', 'bcdefghi'], [.....], [....], ... ]
```

I wanted to do this with list comprehension but I am stuck. Is it possible to implement.? Are there any other faster alternatives.?

Comment: Why does your expected output with K=3 not start with `['a','b','cdabcdabcdabcdabcdefghi']`?

Comment: I just gave a random sample. The order doesn't matter

Comment: Do you want every possible combination of `K` sublists?

Comment: I want to get every possible combination of K sublists. I am looking for some faster method. List comprehension most preferably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), you can get separation index pairs:

```
>>> s = 'abcdef'
>>> k = 3
>>> list(combinations(range(1, len(s)), k-1))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
```

using that index pair to get string slices

- `(1, 2)` -> (`s[:1]`, `s[1:2]`, `s[2:]`)
- `(1, 3)` -> (`s[:1]`, `s[1:3]`, `s[3:]`)
- ...
- `(4, 5)` -> (`s[:4]`, `s[4:5]`, `s[5:]`)

---

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> s = 'abcdef'

>>> k = 3
>>> [[s[i:j] for i, j in zip((None,) + idxs, idxs + (None,))]
...  for idxs in combinations(range(1, len(s)), k-1)]
[['a', 'b', 'cdef'], ['a', 'bc', 'def'], ..., ['abcd', 'e', 'f']]


>>> k = 4
>>> [[s[i:j] for i, j in zip((None,) + idxs, idxs + (None,))]
...  for idxs in combinations(range(1, len(s)), k-1)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'def'], ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'ef'], ..., ['abc', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

- `s[:1] == s[0:1] == s[None:1]`
- `s[2:] == s[2:len(s)] == s[2:None]`

Comment: @SreeramTP, Time complexity is same as far as I know. But other solution (Filip Młynarski) works only for k=3 case. To go future you need to add another `for` loop(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could find all slices of your list so that none of sliced parts will be empty without any extended libraries like so:

```
s = 'abcd'
substrings = []

# find slice of first part - from a|bcd to ab|cd
for first_slice in range(len(s)-2):
    # find slice of second and last part, for bcd - from b|cd to bc|d
    #                                     for cd -  just c|d
    for second_slice in range(first_slice+1, len(s)-1):
        substrings.append([s[:first_slice+1], s[first_slice+1: second_slice+1], s[second_slice+1:]])

print(substrings) # -> [['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['ab', 'c', 'd']]

s = 'abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdefghi'
print(len(substrings)) # -> 276
```